# The quickest way possible to save Matlab matrices

Tags: performance, file, matlab, save

I am using Matlab to invoke some external call in C++ and then receive a huge calculated matrix back. The matrix is very huge, and I do not have access to this C++ program's source code. (if I have, I will make it save from C++ right away)

Right now, on my system, this C++ program only uses 1 second to calculate the given data and send back to Matlab, and Matlab's dlmwrite takes 200-300 seconds to save this single huge array on disk. I have some more thousands to compute, and I wanna cut the time down.

So what is the fastest way possible to save in Matlab?

Comment: What do you want to do with the saved data? Read them in Excel? Only use them in MATLAB?

Comment: This processed data will be used elsewhere further by several other programs.

Comment: That is not terribly helpful. What input format can you make the other programs accept?

Comment: The other programs right now accept strings, as input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way possible is probably Matlab's [save](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) command. Alternatively, you could [fwrite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html) the whole matrix to a binary file.

Using `dlmwrite` converts the values to text, which takes time and is more data to write to disk. Don't do that unless you really need to have the data in that format. Note that `dlmwrite` will be faster if called one time with a big matrix instead of in a loop that incrementally writes your file.

Comment: I've tested `a = zeros(10000); dlmwrite(...) takes 89.5 sec while save(...) takes 2.68 sec` Now, that's impressive.

Comment: But unfortunately, if I am going to use mat files from the save function, I will have to dig into reading mat files.

Comment: @Karl Reading .mat files can be complex depending on your data. `fwrite` is probably as fast as `save`, but then you have to decide on your own custom binary format and be able to write and read it.

Comment: I see that save has one drawback though: that is it cannot be used in parfor. Nevertheless, if parfor is not required, save is the fastest.

Comment: On the other hand, if you wanna "write" data in parfor loop, you can go for mex file and call the mex function in parfor loop. Look here for more info: http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/243930

Answer (score 2):

If you want a Matlab only solution, I would probably use fwrite for binary or fprintf for ASCII. However, I like to mix Matlab and Java when it comes to IO since this is usually faster. I would do something like

```
Java Code
package mypackage.release;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException


public class MatrixWriter {
  public static void write(String fileName, double[] matrix) throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
    for (double d : matrix)
      dos.writeDouble(d);
    dos.close();
  }
}

Matlab Code
import mypackage.release.MatrixWriter;
M = get matrix from c++;
MatrixWriter.write('myfile.dat', M(:));
```

This is something off the top of my head, but I use variations of this all the time. Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please show some result of your code VS dlmwrite at least?

Comment: sure. 
m=zeros(1000);
tic; dlmwrite('temp.dat', m); toc;
Elapsed time is 2.296942 seconds

tic; MatrixWriter.write('temp.dat', m(:)); toc
Elapsed time is 0.252032 seconds

Comment: fyi, just compared it to fwrite, and it is faster in this case. Unless you are doing something more complex that might be the best way to go.